# Image of group homorphism between $GL_2(\mathbb{F_3})$ and $S_4$ induced by group action

Tags: vector-spaces, permutations, group-actions, group-homomorphism, general-linear-group

I am given the set $W$ of 1-dimensional vector subspaces in the $\mathbb{F_3}$-vector space $\mathbb{F_3^2}$. (We know that |$W$|$=4$).

The group $G:=GL_2(\mathbb{F_3})$ actson the set $W$ in the following way:

$$ g·V := \{g·w | w \in V \} \in W (g \in G, V \in W) $$

I need to show:

(a) This operation induces a group homomorphism $f: G - S_4$.

(b) Determine the $ker(f), im(f)$ and the order of G.

I have been able to prove (a), via the homomorphism defined as follows:

\begin{align*}
f: G&\rightarrow S_4\\
g&\mapsto \pi_g
\end{align*}, where 
\begin{align*}
\pi_g: W&\rightarrow W\\
w&\mapsto g·w
\end{align*}

Also, I've obtained that $ker(f)$ is the intersection of all the stablisators of elements $w \in W$. However, I don't seem to be able to determine $im(f)$ (I know that the order of $G$ is 48).

There is a further question:

(c) Consider the following subgroups of $G$

$$ N=\{S \in G | det(S)=1, S^2=+-E\}, H=\{\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix} | b, d \in \mathbb{F_3}; d \neq 0 \} $$

Show that $G=H·N$.

I have barely made progress with (c). I think you may have to use the second isomorphism theorem, but I can't get beyond that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that if $u$ is in the kernel, every vector of $\mathbb{F}_3^2$ is an eigenvector of $u$, so $u$ is scalar. In other words $\ker{f}=\{\pm Id\}$. It follows that the image of $f$ has cardinality $48/2=24$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully follow your reasoning nor language, could you add some references? (I'm not sure what "scalar" means in this context)

Comment: Let $u \in G$ be such that $u$ induces the identity on all subspaces of dimension $1$ of $V=\mathbb{F}_3^2$. I claim that $u$ is $\pm Id$, and thus, that $\ker{f}$ has exactly two elements. Moreover, $|im(f)|=\frac{|G|}{|\ker{f}|}=24=|S_4|$, thus $f$ is surjective.

Comment: It's the claim I'm not sure how to prove... :/ Thanks a lot for your help. Have you got any hint on (c)?

Comment: I don’t get what $H$ is. For the claim: let $(a,b)$ be the canonical base of the vector space. We have $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \{\pm 1\}$ (because $u$ is invertible and preserves the vector lines) such that $u(a)=\alpha a$, $u(b)=\beta b$, $u(c)=\gamma c$. In particular $\gamma a +\gamma b=\gamma c=u(c)=u(a)+u(b)=\alpha a +\beta b$ so $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ thus $u=\beta Id$. You had better learn the statement and the proof, it really is useful.

Comment: H is the subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{F_3})$ formed by the matrices of that form

Comment: Right, I mis-wrote. I meant $N$ and $E$.

Comment: E is the identity of G, and N is the special linear group with the additional restriction that the elements S verify S^2=+,-Id.

Comment: And sorry again, one last question about your proof: c is a random vector? Then shouldn't the coordinates of c be in the equation u(c)=u(a)+u(b)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t define it. $c$ is defined to be $a+b$.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help and patience!